# Http rxjs - Passing Subscribe result to another function

Tags: http, rxjs, httpclient, angular6, subscribe

Please would you kindly guide me in the right direction?

I am trying to pull records from an old Http REST service, restructure the data, then post it to firebase.

I'm not sure if this is the completely wrong approach or I misunderstand observable's completely. Your guidance will be most appreciated. How to send this new listing to another DataService function: exportToFirebase(new_listing) ?

```js
onServiceCall() {
  this.httpDataService.getData().subscribe((itemData) => {
    this.itemDataJSON = itemData;
    if (this.itemDataJSON) {
      this.itemDataJSON.forEach(function(value) {
        let new_listing = new Listing(value.id, value.name, value.category);
        //console.log(new_listing);
        //How to send this new listing to another firebaseDataService function exportToFirebase(new_listing);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: You can't "send" the data, but on the other hand you can pull. So instead of sending it from `onServiceCall()`, at your `DataService`, call `this.httpDataService.getData()` and then use `.switchMap` or `.map` to do whatever you want with your results.

Comment: Whats the function signature of exportToFirebase

Comment: What does `exportToFirebase` returns?

Answer (score 1):

This [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-so-http-to-firebase?file=app/hello.component.ts) does what you want, using mocked http & firebase services.

```
// --- make http call
httpCall.pipe(
  // --- construct an array of "new_listing" (of just one, up to u) and pass along the observable chain
  concatMap(httpNumbers => of(...httpNumbers)),
  // --- make the firebase call
  concatMap(number => firebaseCall(number))
).subscribe(val => console.log(val))
```

Hope this helps. If this does not make sense, then you need to read up on [RxJS](https://www.learnrxjs.io/).